# How to set margin/padding for x-axis first/last point in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I need some space before the first point and after the last point in the line chart showing below (red rectangle area). How do I achieve that in 
MPAndroidChart?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure and I cannot test it right now, but can you give this method a try? `setViewPortOffsets(20, 0, 20, 0)`

Comment: No I just tried. It offsets the whole chart (including labels).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @Hengstar? I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: Nope unfortunately. @Franco

Comment: One (very ugly) workaround I found was to add dummy values at the begin and end of the chart with `y = 0`, which works well for a bar chart, but might look bad for a line chart like yours.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the same workaround too but it was too hacky to be used.

Comment: @Hengstar any solution did you found?

Answer (score 12):

@hengstar.
I meet the same question like you. The following codes work for me. I hope it will to help to you.

```
xAxis.setSpaceMax(0.5f);
xAxis.setSpaceMin(0.5f);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
To start x - axis from 1st position add this code

xAxis.setAxisMinimum(mLineData.getXMin() - 0.5f);
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(mLineData.getXMax() + 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
 /**
 * Set an extra offset to be appended to the viewport's right
 */
setExtraRightOffset(25f);
/**
 * Set an extra offset to be appended to the viewport's left
 */
setExtraLeftOffset(25f);
```

Comment: have you tried to set axis minimum and maximum?
`XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(1);
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(31);`
use values slightly below and above your range

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand well. Firstly I see neither `setAxisMinimum ` nor `setAxisMaximum` method. I only see `setAxisMinValue` and `setAxisMaxValue` and they didn't work too. Then, in my case, the X values are a bunch of strings. I am not quite sure how to set a range below or above a string label.

Comment: Well, actually `setAxisMinValue(-1.f)` seems to work. But I tried a range of numbers for `setAxisMaxValue` and haven't found one working yet.